# WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup, org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4

Tags: websphere

I am trying to ripple start my cluster, but getting below error:

[10/25/18 20:30:31:311 CEST] 00000001 WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:490)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:555)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:311)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:224)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:697)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:413)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:174)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:867)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:605)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:157)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1362)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1697)
        at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:473)
        at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:95)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.(EJSServerORBImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:50)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:482)
        ... 34 more

As per other posts in stackoverflow, this is problem with bootstrap port. As I am using cluster, I assume default ports will be 9809/9810. But, there is no entry for these ports in /etc/services.

How I can proceed here? I also tried to start individual servers, but got same error. netstat do not have any entry for these ports too.

/etc/services do have an entry for 2809, but I am using cluster. SO, I was not concerned about 2809.

Comment: Use your admin console to find out correct ORB ports for your cluster members. Then check if these ports are available. I'm guessing here, but probably your server was not correctly stop e.g. due to incorrect credentials, and then it failed to start as ports were already taken by still running old jvm.

Comment: I have changed the ORB ports for both cluster members, but getting same issue.

Comment: i have done a proper server cleanup and then installed the apps again with new cluster. Still getting same issue.

Comment: getting this:[10/26/18 14:05:52:305 CEST] 00000001 ORBRas        E com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport createServerSocket P=546306:O=0:CT ORBX0390E: Cannot create listener thread. Exception=[ org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CAUGHT_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CONFIGURING_SSL_SERVER_SOCKET, Exception=org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: UNABLE_TO_CREATE_SSL_SERVER_SOCKET Exception=java.net.BindException: The socket name is already in use. (Bind failed)  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 76  completed: No  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 77  completed: No - received while attempting to open server socket on port 46135 ].

Comment: `The socket name is already in use. (Bind failed) ` - something is listening on your socket. Write down all the ports that cluster member is using, then stop all JVMs and use netstat to see if any of these ports is already used by some other software.